# Excel Formula with if, then

Tags: excel, validation, if-statement

I need to write a formula in Excel that performs the following:

If cell A1 contains the text ".png",".jpeg" then cell B1 = Image

If cell A2 contains the text ".mov",".mp4" then cell B2 = Video

And so on...

Also, is it possible to apply this validation with additional validation already applied? Like a list.

Comment: You name what you want done with A1 and A2, then you write "and so on". The formula you want in A1 is not the same as A2, so what does "and so on " mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

I broke the solution to parts so you won't be shocked by a long line of formula.

What I need to get it to work

1. Extract the suffix of a string, I've done that using the length of the string in column B and then putting it in column C.

   ```
   B2=LEN(A2)
   C2=IFERROR(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(".",A2)),$J$4)
   ```

   The IFERROR is in case the file doesn't contain a dot and then column C will show the message in cell $J$4.
2. Get the type by a so called "database" table which I've built to map which suffix belongs to which type of file

   ```
   D2=IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$G$8,MATCH(C2,$F$2:$F$8,0),2),$J$6)
   ```

   I've used the INDEX and MATCH functions to fetch the data from the database.
   The IFERROR in this case means - I didn't find the desired prefix in the Database table (in $F$2:$G$8)

After filling these formulas, drag down the data to the rest of the cells and you'll get the desired results.

Here's an image of my Excel file and below it you'll see the cells mapping to prevent you from guessing where is what.

[image]

## Cells Mapping

- Database = $F$2:$G$8
- No Dot string = $J$4
- Not a valid suffix string = $J$6

Comment: Thank you! This was great info!

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(
   OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,".png")),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,".jpeg")))
   ,"Image"
   ,IF(
       OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,".mov")),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,".mp4")))
   ,"Video"
   ,"")
)
```

Please check for the closing brackets yourself as I just typed this off my head.

That formular should be used for cell B1

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get that to work in Excel though. I'm putting that in as a custom formula under data validation. And now that I'm thinking about it I really should have asked for this:


If cell A1 contains the text ".png","jpeg" then B1 = Image, If cell A1 contains the text ".mov" then B1 = Video